# What is Iron Ore used for in leatherworking?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have been mining *Iron Ore* and I have maxed out my collectibles store (250 lumps). I've been able to use it since I became level 75 in leatherworking, but I have no idea what I can use it for.

**What can leatherworkers use *Iron Ore* for?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: As it seems for me only for the **Runes of the Engineer**.

These are the recipes I found who uses *Iron Ore*:

- [Minor Rune of the Engineer](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Minor_Rune_of_the_Engineer)
- [Major Rune of the Engineer](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Major_Rune_of_the_Engineer)
- [Superior Rune of the Engineer](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Superior_Rune_of_the_Engineer)

I haven't found othere recipes for it, but maybe another user may know more than me.

---

**EDIT:** Well, just look on the [Iron Ore wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Iron_Ore) page and look for *Recipes -> Leatherworker*. Seems as my mentioned runes are the only recipes that need *Iron Ore*.